# I need help using the limit comparison test for $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to determine whether the following series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$$

I'm having trouble finding a series to compare this to but I was thinking maybe $1/n^3$.

Comment: How about $\frac{1}{n}$? Hint: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+3n^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Comment: Where did you get the  1n2+3n2√ from?

Comment: I'll give a little more detail in my answer below. It came from realizing it was a way to make the denominator smaller than your original quantity, but also that it would work nicely with the square root to show you the behavior of the series.

Comment: @JMartinez Usually with Limit Comp Test, it pays off to compare with a function that has the same degree. In this case the square root of a quadratic term, so that's linear. And so as Graydad indicated, compare with 1/n The limit comp test results in L=1 and so the given series diverges (WHY?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$(n + 1) ^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 > n^2 + 1$$

Alternatively we may use the [Limit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1/(\sqrt{n^2 +1})}{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} = \color{#f05}1 > 0$$

then $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$ diverges because $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: How come it diverges if the limit is 1?

Comment: Take a look at the Limit test first. Then I'll answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt{n^2+1}< n+1\ \forall n\ge 1$$ What does this tell you about the series?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ \qquad n^2+1 \leq n^2+3n^2, \space $ hence  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+3n^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$